# How do you create and use functions in Arel that are not bound to a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

Lets say I want to create:

```
SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE memberships.expires < NOW()
```

I attempted:

```
fn = Arel::Nodes::Function.new("NOW")
memberships = Arel::Table.new("memberships")
memberships.project(Arel.star).where(
  memberships[:expires].lt(fn)
)
```

Which give `TypeError (Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Function)`.

All the sources I have found when just cover using Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction to create functions that are bound to a specific attribute. I do know there are other ways to solve this like sql literals but I'm curious as to how to actually use `Arel::Nodes::Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction`.

This class initializes with the name of the function and an arguments array. The Vistor for a NamedFunction will assemble the SQL as `FUNCTION_NAME(comma, separated, arguments)`.

Since `NOW` has no arguments all we need to do is pass an empty arguments array.

```
fn = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new("NOW",[]) 
memberships = Arel::Table.new("memberships")
memberships.project(Arel.star).where(
  memberships[:expires].lt(fn)
).to_sql 
#=> "SELECT * FROM [memberships] WHERE [memberships].[expires] < NOW()"
```

[`Function`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/nodes/function.rb) appears to be a super class for inheritance purposes only, children include `Sum`,`Exists`,`Min`,`Max`,`Avg`, and `NamedFunction` (which allows you to call any other function by name as shown above)

Comment: Thanks - it totally clicked with the "and an arguments array" part. I was thinking about it totally wrong.

Comment: @max no problem. Its nice to help you out on an arel question for once, since you always steal the good ones an I just end up commenting :)